# Include assembly in local Mono Framework Build

Tags: c#, .net, makefile, mono

First time contributor to the Mono Project. (attempting to be a contributor at least)

I'm attempting to add an attribute class to `System.Web.Security`. This class extends `ValidationAttribute` which lives in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly. This assembly for some reason cannot be found when I run `make`in the `./mcs/class/System.Web` subdirectory of the mono project. (or for that matter when I run `make` from the root directory).

I have found the relevant places to add references TO my code so that it is built (hence the build errors).... However, I cannot find out how to include additional assemblies to make them "visible" to the assembly when I run `make`.

I've reached out to the #MonoDev and #Mono irc channels but the response has been relatively slow. I'm grepping like crazy to try and find where the dependent assemblies are defined but I just can't find anything.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: I've finally found something interesting..... added this to the make file line 258:  -r:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations \. Is that the proper way to do this? It now builds at least :)

Comment: The above appears to have worked but I still cannot see my class in Xamarin when I point to my local build/install of the framework.

Comment: I have pointed to a version of System.Web.dll that was build in my /lib/mono/ directory. I can now see my class but I'm getting an invalid cast from the HttpRuntime class when it reads the httpRuntimeSection and casts it to a type of HttpRuntimeSection. I feel like referencing the assembly directly like this is causing the issue as was getting quite a bit further prior.